# Is BLE wakeup from app running in the background possible?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is it possible to use BLE wakeup to a Bluetooth product on iOS/Android if the app is running in the background but not terminated?

Example: App should wake-up product and turn it on at a specific time.

Comment: On the Android side, have you looked into something like AlarmManager? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 0):

I've only worked on BLE stuff using iOS, but maybe this will help.

Using iOS jargon, it sounds like you are asking if your iOS/Android device could be a PERIPHERAL and your ble device could act as a CENTRAL.

You would need to make sure that the device you're trying to wake is a compatible iBeacon device or that both your ios/android device and your BLE device are using a 3rd party SDK.

Background processing iOS:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW1

BLE iOS transaction example:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html

iBeacon info:
https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/

3rd party SDKs... no guarantee this will work for your scenario.

Stick N Find: 
https://www.sticknfind.com/SDK/

Gimbal:
https://gimbal.com/doc/proximity/ios.html

Answer (score -2):

On iOS, at least,you cannot execute code at a specific time unless you are the foreground app.  BLE background mode allows you to respond to data that is sent from the peripheral/device (and once you have received the data in the background you could also write some data back).

If you need the device to turn on at a specific time then you really need the device to track the current and desired activation times itself - Your app could send the desired activation time to the device.

Even if you can activate the device from the background on Android I would have thought it was better to have the device act autonomously - what if your phone is switched off/out of range?  Of course, that depends on your exact scenario.